# SWIFT - can't get response.result.isSucess

Tags: swift

I make a Weather App and need please help...
I can't make response.result. "isSuccess" but idk why?
look at my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Alamofire

class WetterViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    // MARK: Outlet

    @IBOutlet weak var WetterImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var StatusLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: Properties

    let weatherURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    let appID = "3084f92d04fb27b6dd25f1a3a8afd221"

    var data: [String: String] = [:]
    {
        didSet
        {
            getWeatherData(from: weatherURL, with: data)
        }
    }

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // MARK: View Controller Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:     [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations[locations.count - 1]

        let latitude = String(location.coordinate.latitude)
        let longitude = String(location.coordinate.longitude)

        data = ["lat": latitude,
                "lon" : longitude,
                "appid": appID]
    }

    func getWeatherData(from url: String, with parameters: [String: String])
    {
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).response { response in

            if response.result.isSuccess (but I can't get isSuccess, what is the problem?)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this and check what your input parameters are set to and what you actually get in `response`?

Comment: I check many things but I can´t to explain

Comment: One thing that might be related is that you call the Rest API each time you get a location update and that could mean you make a lot of calls which might lead yo getting an error back if the API has a limit on how many calls you can make in a time period. Anyway if you run it in the debugger or add some print statements you should get some clue on what is going on.

Comment: idk. I´m a beginner, my English isn't the best and I can´t fix it... :( only what I want is to check if weather data can read, I want to write: ------------------------------------------------func getWeatherData(from url: String, with parameters: [String: String])  {
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).response { response in

            if response.result.isSuccess (but I can't get isSuccess, and idk why... )
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `response.result` is a `Swift.Result` type, you should use:

```
if value = try? response.result.get() {
    // Handle success
}
```

Comment: There are several `Result` types in different frameworks, you might want to clarify which one you mean